# What is the word for a corollary that follows from a proof?

Tags: terminology

I know there's a particular word but can not think of it and have been unsuccessful finding it by googling.  I want to say "porium" but that doesn't come up when I google.

Comment: I’m not aware of one; I simply call it a corollary to the proof. And in writing it up, I’d simply label it **Corollary**, assuming that it directly followed the theorem to whose proof it was a corollary.

Comment: I'd write *Corollary (of the proof)*.

Comment: Oh, you might be thinking of "scholium," I'm sure I've seen that somewhere. But it's nowhere near universal.

Answer (score 5):

You’re thinking of [*porism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porism). I’ve never seen it used in normal mathematical writing, though it comes up in works on the history of mathematics.

Comment: IIRC Charles Weibel uses the word in his book on homological algebra.

Comment: @Mariano: That’s even worse than my using *lemmata* in my dissertation $-$ just because I could. :-)

Comment: "Porism" is used in Heath's translation of Euclid - at a quick glance to represent a consequence of a "proposition" or of its demonstration. The best known use of the term "porism" in Mathematics known to me is "Steiner's Porism" - but it has never been obvious to me what the original proposition was of which this might be an obvious consequence.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for ["porism"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porism).